# How to detect if JavaVM is downloaded on Mac OsX 10.7

Tags: java, macos, jvm

On Mac OSX 10.7 JavaVM is automatically downloaded when first used (when some application loads /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/JavaVM). But if JavaVM is not present, application ends immediately with exit code 97.

My question is, is there any way to programmatically (ideally methods in carbon) determine if JavaVM is already downloaded and installed, so my app can behave accordingly?

My app is written in c++, it's basically native launcher for java app.

Comment: *"so my app can behave accordingly?"* Is your app. written in Java?

Comment: spawn a process `java -version` and see if the command can be executed.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Spawn a process java -version basically works, but it automatically start downloading java and I prefer not to,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way. If java is not installed /usr/libexec/java_home doesn't return java home dir and doesn't start download. Downloading could be started by parameter --request.

Anyway would prefer some API.